# How to make code stop running after resolve or reject from EventEmiter

Tags: node.js

I was trying to make a downloader, but now I struggle with download-remove.
My concept is pretty simple. Delete the files, and stop the download process if there's one.
My current problem is that code is still proceeding after the `download-removed` event received although I returned rejected.

This is for Node.js, and I don't use such external modules like `bluebird` or so, thus please provide plain javascript code if possible.

```js
function download(id) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      // some logics to define both *links* and *size*
      process.on("download-removed", ($id) => {
        console.log("removed")
        if (id === $id) {
          console.log("matched")
          return reject("download-removed");
        }
        console.log("unmatched")
      });
      // from here, when event received, code should be stop as reject returned
      for (let index in links) {
        console.log("start", (index, size - links.length + Number(index) + 1));
        this._current = path.join(this._directory, String(id), `${(index, size - links.length + Number(index) + 1)}.${/\.([a-zA-Z]+)(\.webp)*$/.exec(links[index])[1]}`);
        await global.toolkits.download(links[index], this._current, false, `https://my_website/${String(id)}.html`).then((response) => {
          this._current = null;
          switch (response) {
            case "downloaded":
            case "file-exist": {
              console.log("end");
              let copy = [...links];
              copy.splice(0, index);
              process.emit("download-progress", id, (index, size - links.length + Number(index) + 1), size);
            }
          }
        });
      }
      this._current = null;

      if (this._process.length) {
        this.download(this._process[0]);
        this._process.splice(0, 1);
      }
      console.log("return", id);
      return resolve("downloaded");
      // to here!
    });

  remove(id) {
    process.emit("download-removed", id);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    this._process = this._process.filter((value, index, array) => { return value !== id; });
    fs.rmdirSync(path.join(this._directory, String(id)), { recursive: true });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there is a few possible solutions:

1. Run download process in separate [thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) or [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) and kill the process on event
2. Create some global variable like `let DOWNLOAD_ALLOWED = true` and verify it's status before each load step (while you iterate through links). On system event, change `DOWNLOAD_ALLOWED` to `false` and exit your load script.